# JQuery Mobile event on Page Load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

i'm using this code to animate a collapsible content in a html5+jquryMobile app...i add it to my head:

```
$(document).on('expand', '.ui-collapsible', function() {
   $(this).children().next().hide();
   $(this).children().next().slideDown(500);
})

$(document).on('collapse', '.ui-collapsible', function() {
   $(this).children().next().slideUp(500);
});
```

it works fine when i click on the collapsible head...i'd like to use it for all my collapsible elements but in some pages i'd like to have the animation automatically after the page is loaded...
some one can help me?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vmZyn/

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().hide();
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().slideDown(1500);
});
```

You want to use a **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** event. At that point page you can animate sliding.

In case you want to do it only one (like document ready) use this syntax instead:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){       
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().hide();
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().slideDown(1500);
});
```

Unlike **pageshow**, **[pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)** will trigger only once.

Comment: the code with pageshow works fine...but how i can avoid that when i reload the page the collapsible is still open?!...it's opened for a second and then the slideDown restart..

Comment: Add data-collapsed="true" attribute into collapsible div. For more info  look at official documentation : http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#option-collapsed , everything you need is there.

Comment: i tried to use the data-collapsed=true...the problem persist...in others collapsible elements (without animation) the element was collapsed when i load the page for the first time...if i change page with the element opened when i recharge that page it is open and i can't close it...?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body onLoad='expand();'>
```

and then put the necessary in a function

```
<script>
 function expand()
{
$(this).children().next().hide();
   $(this).children().next().slideDown(500);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work in jQuery mobile: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/dom-ready-not-working.html

Answer (score 0):

JQM has its own eventing that you need to hook into.  Docs here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

If you want to trigger an event on certain pages use this syntax:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#some-page", function() {
   ...
});
```